# Python seaborn / matplotlib - show frequency in legend categories in sns.countplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have plot generated using sns.countplot with a legend that uses the "hue" parameter. I would like to show the frequency of the "Category" count on the legend, along with the "Cross_Tab" label:

dfData:

```
Category    Cross_Tab
Apple       Yes
Apple       No
Peach       Yes
Peach       No
Dog         Yes
Dog         Yes
```

Plot:

```
fig = sns.countplot(x="Category", hue="Cross_Tab", data=dfData,  order=dfData.Category.value_counts().index)
```

Legend:

```
fig.legend(title="This is the Legend", loc='upper right')
```

This just shows the legend categories:

```
"This is the Legend"
Yes
No
```

Desired output:
The legend of the plot should look like this:

```
"This is the Legend"
Yes (n = 4)
No (n = 2)
```

After looking at various sources - I got as far as this, but it's not working:

```
x = dfData.Cross_Tab.value_counts()
fig.legend("n=(%s)"%(x, ), title="This is the Legend", loc='upper right')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recreate each label individually.

Something like this seem to get the desired output:

```
plt.figure()
ax = sns.countplot(x="Category", hue="Cross_Tab", data=df,  order=df.Category.value_counts().index)

h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
counts = df.Cross_Tab.value_counts().reindex(l)
l = [f'{yn} (n={c})' for yn,c in counts.iteritems()]
ax.legend(h,l, title="This is the legend")
```

[image]